# Swift how to set default text color for UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to set colors for the text and background of UISegmentedControl. So I've four colors to set, the default and selected color of the text and background.

I can use `tintColor` and `backgroundColor` to set the background. But how to set the default text color, not same as the tint color?

**Note**: here is swift3 not the older language. I'm a beginner of ios, I just start from the swift3, have no experience of the former language.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Selected)
```

Comment: I want to set the default text color.

Comment: I find it, check my answer.

Answer (score 35):

**Swift 5+** code to update text color for your `UISegmentedControl` (`sc` in this example)

```
// selected option color
sc.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.green], for: .selected)

// color of other options
sc.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

Comment: should add "NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor" instead of ".foregroundColor"

Comment: @emrcftci That shouldn't be needed, but you can do it :)

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 4.2 +**

```
segmentedControl.tintColor = .black //background
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the workable one:

```
// default background color
customSC.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:65/255.0, green:140/255.0, blue:218/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// selected background color
customSC.tintColor = UIColor(red:65/255.0, green:140/255.0, blue:218/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// selected title text color
customSC.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: UIControlState.selected)

// default title text color
customSC.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGray], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to handle it on storyboard:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
@IBInspectable var textSelectedColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return self.textSelectedColor
    }
    set {
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: newValue], for: .selected)
    }
}

@IBInspectable var textNormalColor: UIColor {
    get {
        return self.textNormalColor
    }
    set {
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: newValue], for: .normal)
    }
}}
```

Comment: This is nice, but getters are recursive which would cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
customSC.backgroundColor= UIColor（red: 0.5, greep: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0）
customSC.tintColor= UIColor（red: 0.5, greep: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0）
```

Comment: I want to set the default text color.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I find it, check my answer.